# read RSA public key as bytes via openssl / c / c++

Tags: c++, c, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to send an RSA public key of 2048 bits (256byte) to a server. I need to read the data as a byte stream.
I don't seem to find a way.

```
BIO *memBio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

ASN1_PCTX *asn1=ASN1_PCTX_new();//useless unless I know how to use it

BIO_set_flags(memBio, BIO_FLAGS_WRITE);
int ret=EVP_PKEY_print_private(memBio,rsaAppKeys,0, asn1 );

BUF_MEM *bptr;
BIO_get_mem_ptr(memBio, &bptr);
BIO_set_close(memBio, BIO_NOCLOSE); /* So BIO_free() leaves BUF_MEM alone */
BIO_free(memBio);
```

It prints in memory the key in a DER format, with hex bytes formatted as strings, and ":" between each byte, and a header. I could parse it but i think there must be a better way. 
In the docs it's written that by using a ASN1_PCTX I can fine tune the output, but I can't find any documentation of it.

Any idea of a simple way to get the key as raw bytes?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok.. I couldn't wait so I devised a dirty hack:

- first I generate a key in  PEM format
- then parse it to extract an ASN.1 structure
- then extract the 2048 bit key from the ASN.1 structure

THe ASN.1 parse is dirty, to say the least. Suggestions welcome

I've used also the excellent http://lapo.it/asn1js/ to explore the ASN.1 structure.
And https://shanetully.com/2012/04/simple-public-key-encryption-with-rsa-and-openssl/ to get a go at printing keys to string in base64 form.

```
//generic method to extract data from an EVP_PKEY
//it's very UGLY. I'm ashamed especially of the ASN.1 parsing (!!)
-(NSData *)getPublicKeyBytes:(EVP_PKEY *)rsaKey{
    ///try to write bytes
    BIO *pub = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

    //write pub key as this format:
    //-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
    //MIIBCgKCAQEA3J7MfnosapxZH9ibxm9Gz88X+ryEEk616BtXGFx3SH1T7ssjdTvv
    //pL8FRAvnmHegtNm0JsCFbEWdGzFr1F7BFYu1lj6h7JFPIhlalMMSlGsRP5dzzj8q
    //....
    //-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
    //
    PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(pub, rsaKey->pkey.rsa);

    size_t pub_len = BIO_pending(pub);

    char *pub_key = malloc(pub_len + 1);

    BIO_read(pub, pub_key, pub_len);
    //zero terminated string
    pub_key[pub_len] = '\0';

    //transform to nsstring
    NSString *plainKey=[[NSString alloc]initWithCString:pub_key encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    //search for header
    NSRange range=[plainKey rangeOfString:@"-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"];
    if(range.location==NSNotFound){
        DLog(@"Error, RSA pub key in wrong format: %@",plainKey);
        return nil;
    }
    //strip header
    plainKey=[plainKey substringFromIndex:range.location+range.length];

    //search footer
    range=[plainKey rangeOfString:@"-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"];
    if(range.location==NSNotFound){
        DLog(@"Error, RSA pub key in wrong format: %@",plainKey);
        return nil;
    }

    //strip footer
    plainKey=[plainKey substringToIndex:range.location];

    //now remove \n
    plainKey=[plainKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    plainKey=[plainKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];
    //DLog(@"Plain key stripped %@",plainKey);

    //now read as byte
    NSData *rsaBytes=[NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:plainKey];
    //DLog(@"Data is %d len %@",rsaBytes.length,rsaBytes);
    //unfortunately data is in a ASN1 rame;;
    //it's a sequence of 2 element, integer and exponent (65537).
    //the key starts from byte 9, or 10.. (byte 9 is a zero).
    NSData *pubKeyBytes=[rsaBytes subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(9, 256)];
    DLog(@"pubKeyBytes is %d len %@",pubKeyBytes.length,pubKeyBytes);

    return pubKeyBytes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create RSA public key from der encoded byte stream using,    `d2i_RSA_PUBKEY()`

then use `BN_bn2bin()` function to convert RSA public keys modulus to a big-endian byte stream.

eg.

```
RSA * pubKey = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(NULL, <der encoded byte stream pointer>, <num bytes>);
BN_bn2bin(pubKey->n, <where to put the result>);
```